# Referrer is blank when using header() in PHP

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers

Surfer is coming from A to B. At B, there's a PHP redirect to C. Site B redirects to C, without giving C referrer information. Site C sees Refferrer field as blank. I'd like site C to see site B as a Refferrer.

Code:

```
<? 
header('Location: [SITE-C.com');...] 
?>
```

This is the index.php on site B which does the redirection to Site C.

As of now... NO referrer is getting passed. That is the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14661162/2611927

Comment: Case in that question is that the referrer is kept as “Site A", what I would like to do is changing the referrer to "Site B". @Hardy

Comment: Read the whole answer and use your brains to modify it for your needs.. you can just manually set the site "B" as referer with tag in header `Referer: your site b`

Comment: sorry for being a noob here. I tried but seems the header referer() method does not like IE and Firefox. Would you mind showing some sample code? Thanks!