# How to Simulate Click Redrect Like Human

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, web-crawler

I'm working on a project and I'm blocked by lack of knowledge. The code works but I don't know if the website 3 sees it as if it was clicked by a human.

Let me explain: I have 3 websites in total.

- Website 1 redirect to Website 2 when clicking on a button.
- Website 2 check if the referrer comes from Website 1 and automatically redirect to Website 3.

I need the redirect (Website 2 -> Website 3) to look as if the button was clicked by a human and not to show that I have redirected it automatically.

Code so far:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    $url_info = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    $countCharacter = substr_count($url_info['host'], '.');
    if($countCharacter == 2){
        $eldominio = explode(".", $url_info['host']);
        $elhost = $eldominio[1];
    }else if($countCharacter == 1){
        $eldominio = explode(".", $url_info['host']);
        $elhost = $eldominio[0];
    }

    //if referrer contain $elhost
    if($elhost == 'website1' || $elhost == 'website2'){
        $tieneHostaff = "yes";
    }else{//no host}

} else {  // referrer does not exist 

session_start();
if($tieneHostaff=="yes" && isset($_GET['q']) && !empty($_GET['q'])){
    //Create sessions and delete actual referrer
    $_SESSION['nombre'] = "y";
    $_SESSION['producto'] = $_GET['q'];
    echo "<script>window.location.reload(true);</script>";
    exit();
}

if($_SESSION['nombre'] == "y"){
// Destroy session and redirect to website 3
    session_unset();
    echo "<script>window.location.href = 'https://website3.com/".$_SESSION['producto']."'</script>";
    exit();
}
```

I need the last part to make the redirect (website 2 -> website 3) as if it was clicked by a human.

In the code below I'm getting it but I don't know if it's the best way or if it's right:

```
if($_SESSION['nombre'] == "y"){
// Destroy session and redirect to website 3
    session_unset();
    echo "<script>window.location.href = 'https://website3.com/".$_SESSION['producto']."'</script>";
    exit();
}
```

Website 3 checks referrer and all things to find that it's a human click

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Can you explain what/how it will “look like a human clicked” something means? Who needs to perceive it this? A user, the server’s logs? Are you not wanting the user to know that a redirect happened?

Comment: @ChrisHaas I need to automatically redirect from website 2 to website 3. Website 3 doesn't have to know that it has been automatically redirected, it has to see it as if the user has clicked on a link and has been redirected to website 3.

Comment: There is no "HasClicked" HTTP header. :)  Also, session IDs have no correlation with HTTP referers. It's not advisable to rely on the presence of the referer header, since the user (or an extension they installed) may have turned off the browser's sending referer information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect preserving original referrer field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660818/how-to-redirect-preserving-original-referrer-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically you could issue the click event on the element that handles it, but that's probably as close as you can get without using any sort of external automated testing tool which would do the clicking. PHP is executed on the server side, while JavaScript is executed on the client's side, so it would actually seem like the client's browser did the trigger rather than the application doing it.

```
<script>
    let elementYouWantToClick = document.getElementById('whatever-the-id-is');
    elementYouWantToClick.click();
</script>
```

Comment: What is the difference between window.location.href and click()?

Comment: @Jesiqa `window.location.href` simply changes the current address you are viewing, as if you were to put a different internet address into the field in the browser. `.click()` will trigger the `onClick` events bound to the button and will actually let the application do what's it supposed to as if a user had clicked the button.